# How to go back to previous activite(s)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-actionbar, onbackpressed

so i have Activity A,B, and C. Activity A & B both go to activity C. When i am on activity C and I press the back home button on mySupportActionBar, I want to return to the state of activity (from the state i left it in) I came from. How would i accomplish this?

Here is my onOptionsItemSelected(). So currently, it goes back to the designated parent activity i assigned in manifest to avoid my app from crashing. Because the parent activites require strings from intents.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I would also love to accomplish this onBackPressed().

[image]

Comment: Don't declare a parent activity and just call `finish()` instead of calling `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)`.

Comment: so in manifest, do i need to get rid of the parent activity?

Comment: Actually, it may work just as well without getting rid of the parent activity declaration. Try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android.R.id.home`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The back arrow button is  the "home" button when you're in a inner activity so you could finish the inner activity or maybe just call the back button

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `setNavigationOnClickListener` on toolbar to trigger back button.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter_category);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            //back button action
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> finish());
        }
    }
```